# How to Reverse SSH from Shell Script

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, openwrt

Good afternoon,

I am trying to establish a reverse SSH connection using a shell script.

Below is my calling command, from client to host, and back to client: (important data is replaced with xxxxxx)

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=15 -R 19999:localhost:22 admin@xx.xxx.xx.xx -v "sshpass -p xxxxxxx ssh -f -N -q -L 0.0.0.0:81:localhost:80 root@localhost -p 19999"
```

Show Below are the Output from SSH and from Netstat commands
The connection does show up on Netstat unfortunately, it shows up as TIME_WAIT instead of ESTABLISHED and I cannot access port 80 on client from another machine (by accessing port 81 on host)

Is this the correct way to establish Reverse SSH connection without having to type anything on the host?

If I run the two commands manually

```
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=15 -R 19999:localhost:22 dmin@xx.xxx.xx.xx -v
```

and

```
sshpass -p xxxxxxx ssh -f -N -q -L 0.0.0.0:81:localhost:80 root@localhost -p 19999
```

Everything work, Once it's connected to the host, I do not have any problems, however I cannot do it this way from a script file.

EDIT: I tried different combinations of using -f -N and -q on the client and the host portion of the commands, but I haven't had any successful results. The best I've gotten was to display the client's firmware welcome message

Netstat output after the command was executed:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxxxxxxxx.myvzw.com:xxxx xxxx.us-west-1.compute.xxxxx.com:ssh TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 localhost:49553         localhost:ssh           TIME_WAIT
udp        0      0 xxx.xxxxxxxxx.myvzw.com:xxxx xxxxxxx:ntp          ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
```

Debug Output from top SSH command

```
    OpenSSH_6.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xxx.xx [xx.xxx.xxx.xx] port 22.
    debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ECDSA xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
    debug1: Host 'xx:xxx:xxx:xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:5
    debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
    Authenticated to xx:xxx:xxx:xx ([xx:xxx:xxx:xx]:22).
    debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:19999 forwarded to local address localhost:22
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: remote forward success for: listen 19999, connect localhost:22
    debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
    debug1: Sending command: sleep 5; sshpass -p xxxxxxx ssh -f -N -q -L 0.0.0.0:1195:localhost:1194 root@localhost -p 19999
    debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
    debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 19999, originator ::1 port 38767
    debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) in progress, fd=7
    debug1: channel 1: new [::1]
    debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
    debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 22
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
    debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 2
    debug1: channel 1: free: ::1, nchannels 1
    Transferred: sent 4768, received 4176 bytes, in 10.4 seconds
    Bytes per second: sent 459.7, received 402.6
    debug1: Exit status 0
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have been able to establish a reverse connection by applying some "sleep" commands

Below is my command

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=15 -f -R 19999:localhost:22 admin@XX.XXX.XXX.XX -v "sleep 5; sshpass -p XXXXXX ssh -L 0.0.0.0:81:localhost:81 root@localhost -p 19999 -v \"sleep 120\" sleep 120"
```

So basically I am putting the ssh process to sleep before finishing the second connection and placing the second connection to sleep right afterwards.

Interestingly enough, the connection doesn't cease after 120 seconds, it stays up. If someone would be kind enough to explain why this works, or if there is a better method, please reply
Thanks

Comment: you may need the -t option with ssh if you're not using key authentication.